# Utilizar retorno Json do Ajax no HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, json

### Oi... Tenho os seguintes codigos

HTML

```
<div class="escolha">
          <h5>ESCOLHA A CIDADE</h5>
          <select id="selectMunic" onchange="getMunic(this);">
          </select>
          <div class="Indice"><span>Indice:</span><strong>moradas</strong></div    

 </div>
```

Jquery e AJAX

Obtendo as cidades para exibir no select, cada cidade tem seu indice de moradas correnspondentes, retornado em JSON

```
<script>
    var getMunics = function(){
        $.ajax({
          url: "/city.json", //apenas exemplo... passo a url completa aqui
          method: "GET"
        }).done(function( munics ) {
            $(munics).each(function(){
                $("#selectMunic").append("<option value='" + this.munic + "' >" + this.munic + "</option>");
            })
        });
    }
```

Retornando uma cidade especifica depois de selecionar

```
var getMunic = function(select){
        $.ajax({
          url: "/city.json" + "?munic=" + select.value,
          method: "GET"
        }).done(function( munics ) {
            if(munics.length > 0){
                var munic = munics[0];
                console.log(munic);
            }
        });

    }
```

Verifiquei no console e esta retornando a cidade e o indice de morada
Como faco para exibir o indice  no HTML?

**moradas** - Naturalmente sei que assim nao pode rs

No console confirmei e retornou como no exemplo abaixo

```
{
   id: 1, 
   munic: "Caxias do Sul",
   moradas: 1000 
}
```

Desculpe se estiver meio confuso, e minha primeira pergunta no Stackoverflow e tambem pela falta de acentos nas frases.

Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

### Acho que consegui um caminho...

JAVASCRIPT

```
var getMunic = function(select){
        $.ajax({
          url: "/city.json" + "?munic=" + select.value,
          method: "GET"
        }).done(function( munics ) {
            if(munics.length > 0){
                var munic = munics[0];

                //determinei aqui um ID para ser usado no HTML, e eu tenho o 
                //objeto munic com os valores... ao escolher a chave morada, 
                //ele obetem o valor correspondente.

                document.getElementById("morada").innerHTML = munic.morada;

            }
        });

    }
```

determinei aqui um ID para ser usado no HTML, e eu tenho o objeto munic com os valores... ao escolher a chave morada, ele obetem o valor correspondente, por exemplo, 1000

HTML

```
<div class="Indice"><span>Indice:</span><strong><b id="morada"></b></strong></div>
```

Ai estou acessando pelo ID a informacao...

Muito legal. apenas como sao mais dados vou ter que fazer um a um o que pode ser um pouco trabalhoso mas vai funcionar.

Obrigado e espero que possa ajudar alguem.